# Angular2 Webpack doesn't display data

Tags: angular

I'm trying attach webpack the Angular2 Tutorial and it compiles with two warnings and the page loads, but the data doesn't display on the webpage.

WARNING in ./~/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js
5870:15-36 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./~/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js
5886:15-102 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

node 6.4.0 and npm 4.6.1

app.component.html

```
<main>
  <h1>Hello from Angular App with Webpack</h1>
  <img src="../assets/images/angular.png">
</main>
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<h2>My Heroes</h2>
<ul class="heroes">
  <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes"
    [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero"
    (click)="onSelect(hero)">
    <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
<div *ngIf="selectedHero">
  <h2>{{selectedHero.name}} details!</h2>
  <div><label>id: </label>{{selectedHero.id}}</div>
  <div>
    <label>name: </label>
    <input [(ngModel)]="selectedHero.name" placeholder="name"/>
  </div>
</div>
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<h2>{{hero.name}} details!</h2>
<div><label>id: </label>{{hero.id}}</div>
<div>
  <label>name: </label>
  <input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name">
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import '../assets/css/styles.css';

export class Hero {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

const HEROES: Hero[] = [
  { id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice' },
  { id: 12, name: 'Narco' },
  { id: 13, name: 'Bombasto' },
  { id: 14, name: 'Celeritas' },
  { id: 15, name: 'Magneta' },
  { id: 16, name: 'RubberMan' },
  { id: 17, name: 'Dynama' },
  { id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ' },
  { id: 19, name: 'Magma' },
  { id: 20, name: 'Tornado' }
];

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Tour of Heroes';
  heroes = HEROES;
  selectedHero: Hero;
  onSelect(hero: Hero): void {
    this.selectedHero = hero;
  }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }  from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms'; 

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```